# Retrieve the value of the radiolisttile in another page

Tags: flutter

I have a settings page where I have radiolisttile which are kept with shared preferences which shows me a list of files which is stored in google drive.
the list returns the name and id of each file.
In another page I have a button which must show me the file according to the value of the radio.
so i want to retrieve the value which should be the id for the button link.

Thank you for your help

```
Future<void> _listGoogleDriveMeubles() async {
    var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount!.authHeaders);
    var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
    drive.files
        .list(pageSize: 20, q: "'MASQUED' in parents")
        .then((value) {
      setState(() {
        meubles = value;
      });
      for (var i = 0; i < meubles!.files!.length; i++) {
        idDevisMeubles = meubles!.files![i].id;
        print(
            "Id: ${meubles!.files![i].id} File Name:${meubles!.files![i].name}");
      }
    });
  }

  List<Widget> generateFilesMeuble() {
    List<Widget> listItem = <Widget>[];
    if (meubles != null) {
      for (var i = 0; i < meubles!.files!.length; i++) {
        listItem.add(Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RadioListTile(
                  title: Text(meubles!.files![i].name ?? ''),
                  value: meubles!.files![i].id ?? '',
                  groupValue: selectedDevisMeuble,
                  onChanged: (String? newValue) => setState(() {
                        selectedDevisMeuble = newValue;
                      })),
            ),
            // child: Text(meubles!.files![i].name ?? ''),
          ],
        ));
      }
    }
    return listItem;
  }
```

In another page I have a button which must show me the file according to the value of the radio.
so i want to retrieve the value which should be the id for the button link.

Thank you for your help

```
Container(
                        width: 160,
                        height: 160,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage('assets/cuisinella_cleanup.png'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        )),
                        child: TextButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            if (isLoading) return;
                            setState(() => isLoading = true);
                            await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
                            const url =
                                'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=ID FILE FROM RADIOLISTTILE';
                            final file = await PDFApi.loadNetwork(url);
                            openPDF(context, file);
                            setState(() => isLoading = false);
                          },
                          child: isLoading
                              ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                )
                              : const Text(
                                  'devis meuble',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

Comment: I can't understand where the sharedprefs part is. But, your second page is a child from the first ? if yes, i think you can pass an id in the constructor. Otherwise you need a state management system

Comment: try to check callback method